# jquery to create table as string and control number of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to display results from a web API in a popup on my site. The results need to be formatted into a table inside the popup where the number of columns can be set (in example below are set to 2 columns). I am using $.each statement to iterate through the data and build the html table, but get errors (see below for note). Also, my popup is expecting a string value for content (refer to variable "content" below) so not sure how to best create the string with table values. Please see below for where I am stuck - I appreciate your help and let me know if questions. Thanks.

Sample of my data:

```
[
    {
        "var1": 1,
        "var2": "foo"
    },
    {
        "var1": 2,
        "var2": "bar"
    },
    {
        "var1": 3,
        "var2": "etc"
    }
]
```

Function to get sample data and display in popup:

```
 function GetData() {

        var html = true;
        var numCols = 2; //assign the number of columns to build

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://my/api/call',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                var content = "";

                var i = data.length;
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                if (!(i % numCols)) tRow = $('<tr>');
                    tCell = $('<td>').html("<span class=\"content-big\">" + val.var1+ "</span><span class=\"content-small\"> " + val.var2+ "</span> ");
                    content = $('table').append(tRow.append(tCell)); //ERROR: tRow is not defined

                $('.popup').popover({
                    content: content,
                    html: html
                });

            },
            error: function (x) {
                alert(x);
            }
        });
    }
```

UPDATE:

For a 2 column layout, should look like

```
--------------
1 foo | 3 etc
2 bar | 
--------------
```

Comment: Bracketless IF statements often lead to these types of errors. Put in some brackets and I bet this will straighten itself out.

Comment: (or it will make your coding error obvious)

Comment: Thanks, that helps eliminate the table row error, but I am still unable to create the table with columns

Comment: this would be the perfect time to use a JavaScript templating library - you setup a template then just inject the data into it rather than building html manually

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what this is supposed to look like? From what I see, you are adding both values to the same table cell, yet your numCols is set to 2.  This `i % numCols` returns an integer (this is math) yet you are checking it for a boolean. And shouldn't you use `key` in your modulus if you want to know when to start a new row?

Comment: @clrockwell please see above edit for 2 column - thanks

Comment: @rtpHarry I like that idea and will look into it - please post an example if you have one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you're trying to do, but from what I can guess, it looks like you're making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

1) You should never interact with the DOM inside a loop.  There's a large performance hit.  I'm not sure how large your dataset is, but regardless, it's just a best practice.  See: http://jsperf.com/jquery-append-multiple-times-vs-array-vs-html-once/2

So, with that in mind & rather than relying on jQuery to append, etc., just build a string and populate your popover html with that:

```
var table = '';

table = '<table><tbody>';

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    table += ('<tr><td class="content-big">' + row.col1 + '</td><td class="content-small">' + row.col2 + "</td></tr>");
}

table += '</tbody></table>';

$('.popup').popover({
    content: table,
    html: true
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CZ5zW/

UPDATE:

OK, here is your solution if you're unable to modify the data structure:

```
var data = [
    {
        span1: 1,
        span2: "foo"
    },
    {
        span1: 2,
        span2: "bar"
    },
    {
        span1: 3,
        span2: "etc"
    }
];

var numberOfColumns = 2;

var table = '<table><tbody>';

var currentColumnNumber = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var td = data[i];    
    if(currentColumnNumber === 1) {
        table += '<tr>';
    }
    table += ('<td><span class="content-big">' + td.span1 + '</span><span class="content-small">' + td.span2 + "</span></td>");

    currentColumnNumber ++;    
    if(currentColumnNumber > numberOfColumns) {
        table += '</tr>'; 
        currentColumnNumber = 1;        
    }    
}

//make sure the final "</tr>" is added
if (currentColumnNumber > 1) {
    table += '</tr>';   
}

table += '</tbody></table>';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/56FFx/1/

Comment: thanks! I like how you simplified but I still need to be able to set the number of columns (see edit to question above). In the case of a large dataset, a single column popup would be too long

Comment: thank you again, but I have no control over the structure. I think a function to run inside the loop every x iterations where x is the number of columns specified, and which adds a new row to the table

Comment: Thanks! I just managed the same effect by instantiating a counter var using if (counter % colNum == 0) { ... }. Your code has helped me a lot and I appreciate your help!

Comment: yw... glad I could help!